# How to get a file close event on mac osx using python

Tags: python, macos, watchdog, fsevents, file-monitoring

Using python 2.7 on osx 10.9

How to get a **file close event**(when opened file is closed by red cross upper check mark):

1. when file is opened in a tab of file opener (like TextEdit, which
   opens all  files in new tab but there exist only a single process of
   TextEdit running)
2. when file is opened in a new process of file opener( File opener
   which does not follow tabbed property)

So, how to get file close event in above cases? Is it possible to achieve above cases through a common code? I am dealing with different file types. I tried with [MacFSEvents](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MacFSEvents) , [watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog) but do not get the file close event.

Comment: What is the specific context from which your problem arises. What are you trying to ultimately accomplish?

Comment: @sshashank124 I am not getting file close event. I am waiting for a loop to end as soon as opened file is closed.

Comment: If the file for which you are trying to get the close event is opened from python you can do it however if it is open outside the scope of your program then I don't think you will be able to get the close event unless you use some modules as you have already tried.

Comment: @sshashank124 as said, file is opening through different file opener like TextEdit etc.